# When does the Final Fantasy Bow's stats surpass those of Phantom Lv. 9?

Tags: defender-2

Since the Final Fantasy bow auto-upgrades based on your current level, at what point does it surpass the attributes of Phantom (Lv. 9)?

The stats for Phantom Lv. 9 are:

- Strength +9
- Agility +8
- Power Shot +3
- Fatal Blow +4
- Multi-Arrow +3

I'm trying to decide if I should invest in Phantom Lv. 9 or just wait it out and get the Final Fantasy instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At level 55, Final Fantasy has:

- Strength +12
- Agility +8
- Power Shot +3
- Fatal Blow +5
- Multi-Arrow +3

Answer (score 1):

At least in stage 406 level 52, because my bow's stats are:

- Strength +11
- Agility +8
- Power Shot +4
- Fatal Blow +3
- Multi-Arrow +2

Unfortunately, I don't know when that was upgraded.

Comment: Your Fatal Blow and Multi-Arrow are both still less than Phantom, so this is not *surpassing* it. It's a useful answer anyway since I know it will last until at least level 52.

Answer (score 1):

at stage 1233 and lvl 116 it seems to have maxxed out at

Strength +30
Agility +9
Power Shot +4
Fatal Blow +5
Multi-Arrow +4

Answer (score 1):

It does not depend on the stage you are on. It depends on the level. If you are level 50 and over, the legendary bow will surpass the Phantom level 9. As you keep on leveling up, the bow will get stronger until the maximum reach. Just focus on upgrading Mana Research - Spell - City wall. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I got stage 1926 and level 147 and final fantasy are:

Strength 36
Agility 28
Power shot 7
Fatal blow 9
Multi arrow 6